Cl source compilation stripped of any debug information
I've been looking for a certain cl flag that would generate me an executable without any additional debug information, I need to optimize the space I am using as much as possible for my project regarding PE compression.
I remember I came across a stack-OF post a while ago having my precious flag ( and I think the person in that post marked it as being undocumented ) but I lost the thread.
If anyone have seen such a flag walking freely in the wild, please let me know:)
Thank you anyways!

If you must optimize the space by stripping debug information you can use documented /DEBUG:NONE.
By the way, you can also apply the option /O1 to fully optimize the size of the executable without packing OR /O2 for code size, or one of them will be overridden.
